# How to Keep-Alive Perl Script?

Tags: perl

So I have a Perl script on a server. (Linux...). The script takes about 3+ minutes to fully complete, (this is normal for my script). Although the server keeps disconnecting, and my browser says that the server is not responding (it timed out I guess). How can I keep the connection alive for over 3+ minutes? (The client is just waiting for a response from the server. Nothing else on the client side is happening)...

Is this even possible?

Comment: For the sake of all involved.  Work on the script time.  However you could run it periodically and the browser would ask for the latest (cached) output.

Comment: @Back2Basics It's a special type of script,... It needs to be that long. It's based on a for loop that has a sleep(240) in it.

Comment: I know of a line you could take out to speed it up :)  But you could run it every 5 min say.  the consumer would get the almost latest info... like stock market quotes on free websites.

Comment: @Back2Basics I kinda need the sleep() in the script. Not updating anything, just needs a timeout until it can process the next functions. (I understand it's a long time. Which is why I asked this question on how to keep it alive).

Comment: If the server is disconnecting it's your script that is doing this.  Can you post your script? If it's too long, post only the connection management part of it (i.e. the part that receives the connection and the part that sends the response).

Comment: @JimGarrison it doesn't have any proper connections. It just loads basic html once the script is finished. A extremely long for loop...

Comment: Just looking for a way to keep the connection alive... Not shorten the script or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server is closing the connection, you need to increase the server (Apache?) script timeout, which will be a parameter to `mod_cgi` or `mod_cgid` (depending on which one you're using).  If you cannot change the Apache configuration then you might experiment with sending an innocuous HTTP header (i.e. `Connection: keepalive`, which is the default anyway) immediately before starting your processing.  This will probably be sufficient to cause Apache not to give up waiting.